# Can USB/Ethernet bandwidth issues be solved by having more host controllers?

Tags: usb, ethernet, bandwidth

If I have multiple bandwidth-hungry USB/Ethernet peripherals connected to my PC that are causing bandwidth issues, would I be correct to assume that having more USB/Ethernet host controllers would help with the bandwidth issues?

My current understanding is that host controllers are the actual source of the bandwidth and the bandwidth is split between different USB/Ethernet ports, therefore adding more ports doesn't help the bandwidth issue but adding more host controllers does.

So if I'm correct, the bandwidth issues can be solved by having a motherboard with more host controllers or connecting the peripherals through a PCIe card that contains its own host controller. Am I understanding this correctly?

More Information: Lets assume the problem is bandwidth, not software or anything else. I was hesitant to add specific information to keep the question general and applicable for others. In my specific case, I believe the problem is bandwidth because I can control the bandwidth the physical devices use and everything works fine unless a specific threshold is reached for the allowed bandwidth-usage value.

More details:

1. Bandwidth I'm trying to get: I have 3 devices that need 125MB/s and 1 device that needs a minimum of 7MB/s.
2. All the devices are hooked by USB. The 3 that need 125MB/s are hooked by USB3.0 and the other one by USB2.0
3. The USB2.0 port is native to motherboard whereas the 3 USB3.0 ports are auxiliary.
4. The CPU is Intel i5 4570 @ 3.20 GHz.

I'd like to emphasize that I'm not asking if I have bandwidth issues. I'm asking if there is a bandwidth issue, can it be resolved by having more host controllers?

Comment: This is very complicated, so, though I hate to do it, I will just say "No". additional controllers help in specialized circumstances that are more appropriate for server builds than PCs, and are generally used with advanced network architectures. Unless you are physically connected to multiple networks, all your traffic will use one host controller anyway. Why is it that you believe you have bandwidth shortfalls anyway? you might get an improvement for USB by installing an additional card and using the USB ports on it, but I'd recommend confirming you have the problem you think you have.

Comment: The bottleneck can be basically everywhere - software, hardware, interaction of the two. Without giving details (**lots** of details) about your situation, and narrowing down where the bottleneck is, it's impossible to answer this. If the bottleneck is on the software side, adding more host controllers won't help, and might actually make things worse.

Comment: There's no way to give a useful answer without a lot more details. The bottleneck might be in the DMI connection between the CPU and the motherboard chipset. It might be in the CPU's PCI express lanes. It might be in software. We can't know without a lot more details.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz What details are needed exactly to narrow down the cause?

Comment: To start with, what bandwidth you're trying to get and what amount you're measuring. It would also help to know exactly how the devices are hooked up. (For example, is the Ethernet connected to a PCIe port? Or the motherboard? Is the USB port the motherboard's native? Or an auxiliary controller?) Is the CPU an Intel or AMD? Which series?

Comment: why not just to add another usb controller? It should be just around 10$

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have updated my question with those details, except for what amount I'm measuring, I haven't done that yet, is there a standard way to do this? I can estimate what I'm getting to be around 375MB/s.

Comment: @Harry That is my question, assuming the problem is bandwidth, I need another UBS host controller?

Comment: @db7638 yeah, sure... as usb does currently not have a lot of available bandwith, i guess all other system components are out of question (if you work with a mainboard younger than about 10 years). But other comments are right, there could be lots of other causes, why do you knwo it is the bandwith... this is not typical. more typical is voltage (which leads to the same conclusio)

Comment: Since a single USB 3 port should hit 600MB/s, a single PCIe2.0 lane should move 500MB/s, and you're looking to move less than 400MB/s, I doubt you need more controllers.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz In that case, what tests do I need to do to find out what will resolve the issue?

Comment: Ethernet:  As long as there is no other system bottlenecks.  One possible solution is to get a 10gigabit NIC, and a gigabit switch with 1 port for 10g.  Then you have 1250mb/s.  You can get buy multiple NIC or 1 NIC with 2 or 4 NIC built in.  The biggest issue with multiple NIC is you may not have enough of the right pcie slots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, YES multiple USB or Ethernet controllers CAN solve bandwidth issues.

However, there are a number of limitation and conditions.

1. You will NEVER solved the problem with PCI or older slot.
2. pcie  1.0 slots will also make it very difficult.
3. Many motherboards have shared pcie resources you need to deal with.

   a. If you have 2 pcie x16 slots they may only run at x8 if both are used.

   b. Some run at x4 if more than that are used.

   c. These can be solved with the right motherboard and/or CPU.

Using non-shared pcie 3.0 the problem should be solvable.  Even in version 2.0 there is still a significant amount of bandwidth.

A single pcie 2.0 lane, x1, is 500mb/s
  A single pcie 3.0 lane, x1, is 1000mb/s

I don't believe the x2 format is ever used.  So with an x4 slot you have 2000mb/s or 4000mb/s depending 2.0 vs 3.0.  This is enough bandwidth for a 10g network card which uses 1250mb/s plus a bit of overhead.

In addition it is enough for a single NIC card with 4 independent Ethernet plugs to run.

Therefore if you solve your Ethernet issues with 1 or 2 cards and you have 2 or more slots remaining solving your USB issues with additional controllers should work.

Finally, your CPU/chipset has to be able to process the incoming data fast enough to satisfy all your devices.  If you are simply recording data to disk, as in video cameras, then you just need enough read/write bandwidth achievable with approx 4 ssd maybe more or less depending on the performance of the make/model you buy.

If each of those streams was video and you were transcoding it to h265 you would need vastly more CPU power.  Even a single GPU acceleration would not be enough to handle that many streams in real time.

If you are just running a file server that only shares files and doesn't process them much you should have no problems with that.

Comment: +1 There are USB 3.0 add-on cards with 4 individual XHCI controllers running on a PCIe bus expander, e.g. https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815287030&cm_re=usb_3.0_pci_card-_-15-287-030-_-Product

Comment: This is a great comprehensive answer. BTW my CPU needs to process the data in real-time (not save to hard disk). For this purpose, is there a way I can approximate the CPU specifications I need?

Comment: @db7638 What kind of processing?  Simple math add,sub,multiple,divide or decoding and re-encoding? Is it video,audio, or etc data?  Depending on the nature of the data GPU acceleration via opencl, cuda, or etc maybe necessary.  If it is multiple streams of data you can use monitor the CPU usage of 1 stream of data and multiple by the number of streams.

Comment: @cybernard I'm processing images in real-time, the images are acquired from three machine-vision cameras using their API, after acquisition the CPU image data is copied over to GPU for processing, so the only work CPU is continuously doing is acquiring images. Before I limited the bandwidths manually, the CPU and RAM usage (8GB) was almost 100%. The CPU is also handling orientation data through the USB for an HMD. Now that I think about it, the CPU is likely just saving to disk (I don't know exactly how the acquisition API works) but after acquisition I just copy image memory to GPU.

Comment: Based on experience 8gb is probably too low for processing image data.  Once your computer runs out of memory its starts using swap file on your hard drive which is orders of magnitude slower than your RAM.  The swapping action uses even more CPU cycles.  You said you CPU and RAM were almost 100%, get 16gb total.  You need to be below 80% RAM usage 100% of the time.  What OS are you using Windows,Linux, or MAC?  Also monitoring your disk IO would be useful as converting a hdd to ssd would solve any IO issues.

Comment: @cybernard I'm using Windows OS. I'll monitor the disk IO to see if SSD is needed.

Comment: @db7638 Monitor the size of pagefile.sys which is the swapfile.  The file is hidden and system so you will need to change your view options to see it.  In dos  administrative command prompt  **dir c:\ /ah** should show it also.